# How do I transfer large amounts of data from an old external harddrive to a new one?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I have an old external hard drive with ~300GB of data. I tried to copy the data with the standard windows file transfer to a new hard drive.

Unfortunately the process stops at specific files. I think those files are unreadable. Windows 10 unfortunately pauses the whole process at those files.

Is there an easy way to transfer my files where it skips files that can't be transferred?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there an easy way to transfer files where it skips files that can't be transferred?

You can use [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) in a `cmd` shell for this.

Note:

- You might need an elevated shell depending on who owns the files you want to copy.

There are specific options to deal with errors:

> ```
> Copy options
>
> ...
>
> /R:n : Number of Retries on failed copies - default is 1 million.
> /W:n : Wait time between retries - default is 30 seconds.
> /REG : Save /R:n and /W:n in the Registry as default settings.
> ```

You can adjust the values of `n` to suit your requirements (how long to keep trying).

Source [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust File and Folder Copy.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust File and Folder Copy.

Comment: With respect to your "Further Reading", I find SS64 to be an excellent reference site, and frequently recommend it to others.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks. I add it whenever suitable to my answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using SuperCopier 2.2 for years.  It can handle situations like this.  The interface is very straightforward.

It looks like the software has evolved into "UltraCopier", and can be accessed here: http://ultracopier.first-world.info/supercopier.html.  Best luck!!